# Which windows phone SDK can I use in Windows 8.1 + Visual Studio 2012 Premium?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

I need to develop a windows mobile application. I have Windows 8.1 (Enterprise) PC with Visual Studio 2012 Premium. Which version of windows phone SDK can I use?

I searched in net and found here(http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2864215) that SDK 8.0 can not be used with Win8.1+VS2012. Everybody suggesting that I have to use VS2013 with SDK8.1. Is there anyway to use SDK8.1 in VS2012?

Is Win8.1+VS2012 useless for windows mobile development?!

I can not change the OS(8.1) and VS2012; those are fixed. Apart from those, I am free to install/update anything in my PC. Could anyone please let me know a way to make my PC to usable for windows mobile development?